# how to make a home page for wordpress custom theme

Tags: templates, homepage

How does we create a custom home page for word press theme like used in themes for theme forest market. Because mostly the home page is used for recent posts to be shown, but I am having no idea how to make a home page that shows a lot more things on that. Is that uses a specific template or shortcodes or something else. I am talking about like shown below 
http://demo.theme-fusion.com/
if we look at the above given link home page shows lot of things. how could we get these sort of home page. from where that whole data is coming, shortcodes or some thing else.

Simply I want to know how that all these sections are made. is by usage of shortcodes or by a template page. Like buy theme section is coming, and so all other sections. can some one tell in some details please as i want to make pages of some thing that sort.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell it's really done with shortcodes but many themes use a visual builder so you don't really need to know the shortcodes. One of the most used visual builder is Visual Composer plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Create a front-page.php file in your themes root directory or page-templates folder.

Here's a trimmed down example from the Eden theme  by Automatic:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page
 *
 * @package Edin
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'hero' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php edin_featured_pages(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar( 'front-page' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```